# Mocking node modules with jest is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Using typescript, jest, ts-node, i am trying to mock some functions of `fs` module to test my own module.

`tsconfig.json`

```
...
 "target": "ESNext",
 "module": "NodeNext",
 "moduleResolution": "nodenext",  
...
```

`mocking.test.ts`

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'

jest.mock("fs", () => ({
    readFileSync: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("test"),
}));

describe('mock test', () => {
    it('should read file content', () => {
        expect(fs.readFileSync("abcd.test", "utf8")).toBe("test"); //ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'abcd.test' 
    });
});
```

When running the test, I get an error from the **real** `fs` module that tells me that the files doesn't exists. This is not expected, because it should be mocked.

Why isn't it mocked? How to properly mock the module?

Comment: ```
jest.unstable_mockModule('fs', () => ({
    readFileSync: jest.fn().mockReturnValue("test"),
}));

const fs = await import('fs');
```

Comment: You can use: `import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
...
jest.mock('fs', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('fs'),
  readFileSync: () => jest.fn().mockReturnValue("test"),
}));` instead, this should work